# videogular 2 for angular 2 404 error

Tags: javascript, angular

im trying to create a application with angular 2 ,i using videogular 2,and i install videogular 2 with npm and i check my node_modules and videogular2 exist in directory but when i run my application occur an error :

angular2-polyfills.js:126 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/videogular2/core 404 (Not Found)

angular2-polyfills.js:390 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading

and this is my configuration :

```
   System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
      'videogular2': './node_modules/videogular2'
    }
  });
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 2):

just in case if anybody needs answer

this is what you would need to include in you system.config.js after installing via npm install videogular2

```
map:{
'videogular2': 'node_modules/videogular2',
},
packages:{
'videogular2':{
                main: 'core.js',
                defaultExtension:'js'
            }
}
```

Happy coding......

Answer (score 1):

I would add a packages block for videogular2 in the SystemJS configuration:

```
   System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      videogular2: { <-------
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
      'videogular2': './node_modules/videogular2'
    }
  });
  System.import('app/main')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

Comment: @ThierryTemplier why is there need to add node_modules this way?